# Trying to get value of stored procedure - Error: "does not contain a definition"

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER procedure FullSearch(@sumeryFieldOnly as bit,@allPropertyCompany as bit,@txtSearc as nvarchar(200)) 
as 
begin
if @sumeryFieldOnly=1
begin
    select SummaryField,NameCompany,idCompany from propertyCompany where SummaryField like '%'+@txtSearch+'%'
end
if @allPropertyCompany =1 
begin
        select IdCompany, NameCompany,Manager,CenterOfficeAddress,CompanyAddress,Website,EmailCompany,Tel1,Tel2,Country,Province,City,WorkExperience,ResumeManager,HistoryCompany,DescriptionField,SummaryField,'MainPP.aspx?idCompany='+cast(IdCompany as nvarchar(20)) as URL
        from PropertyCompany
        where   NameCompany like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or Manager like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or CenterOfficeAddress like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or CompanyAddress like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or Website like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or EmailCompany like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or Tel1 like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or Tel2 like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or Country like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or Province like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or City like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or WorkExperience like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or ResumeManager like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or HistoryCompany like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or DescriptionField like '%'+@txtSearch+'%' or SummaryField like '%'+@txtSearch+'%'
end

end
```

LINQ

```
     var result = dc.FullSearch(true,false,"abc");
    foreach (var item in result){
        str +=item.SummaryField;
    }
```

str is work fine and show `SummaryField`

**BUT**

```
var result = dc.FullSearch(false,true,"abc");
    foreach (var item in result){
        str +=item.idCompany;
    }
```

returns error:

> Error:'FullSearchResult' does not contain a definition for
>   'IdCompany' and no extension method 'IdCompany' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'FullSearchResult' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Nit picking: it would be **SummaryFieldOnly** - not *SumeryFieldOnly* (in your stored proc parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a case sensitivity issue here.

Within your SP, you have two select statements. In one, you return `idCompany`, and in the other, you return `IdCompany`.

It will probably work fine if you fix that in your SP.

C# is case-sensitive; a class is created for the results of a SP, so it follows that if there are ambiguities in capitalization that issues may appear.

Comment: Did you fix your Stored Procedure, and then delete the Stored Procedure from your LINQ DBML diagram, and then re-add the Stored Procedure to your LINQ DBML diagram?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain with detail?

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a differently shaped resultset based on a param value.

You're seeing this exception because LINQ To SQL maps the resultset to a class `FullSearchResult`. At design-time, it has determined that your resultset from `FullSearch` has the properties/columns from your *first* select statement: `SummaryField`,`NameCompany`,`idCompany`.

At run time, you're attempting to load a whole lot more columns/properties into your result class. If it wasn't the `IdCompany` throwing the error, it'd be `Manager`, and so on.

Recommend you refactor your stored proc to:

- return a predictable, consistently shaped resultset, no matter what the inputs.
- create/define a table variable for the 'widest' result set.
- in your branches, insert into that table variable.
- SELECT all columns from your table at the end of your stored proc.

Comment: this is right .and exchange place first and second if but now show item.idcompany but still when run show eror not object refrence